# url.openStream() to Writer

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, stream, writer

What is the correct way to write from an OutputStream (url.openStream()) to a Writer (it can be a FileWriter or a Stringwriter) without loosing encoding/charset??

```
public static String parseURLContentIntoFile(final URL url, final File fileToFill) throws IOException{      
    return parseURLContentIntoOutputWriter(url, new OutputStreamWriter(FileUtils.openOutputStream(fileToFill),"UTF-8"));        
}

public static String parseURLContentIntoString(final URL url) throws IOException{
    final StringWriter output = new StringWriter(); // Or StringBuilderWriter
    parseURLContentIntoOutputWriter(url, output);
    return output.getBuffer().toString();   //Or output.getBuilder().toString()
}


private static String parseURLContentIntoOutputWriter(final URL url, final Writer writer) throws IOException{

    InputStreamReader in = null;
    BufferedWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        in = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(),"UTF-8");
        for(String line : IOUtils.readLines(in)){ //Uses a buffer internally
                      (...VERY LONG parsing...)
          if (!line.isEmpty()) IOUtils.write(line,out); 
        }
        (...Exception handling and stream closing...)
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know the URL you are reading from is "UTF-8"?

Comment: It says <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"> in header

Comment: Why not `PrintWriter(String fileName, String csn);`?